# Sql Server 2008 Database server Minimum Requirements

Tags: sql-server-2008

Does anybody knows what is the base scenario for the sql server 2008 r2 minimum hardware requirements?. By base scenario I mean: Database Size, average # of transactions, number of users connected, etc...

Comment: You'll need to know things about your DB sizes and users in order to spec a server.

Comment: Eric, thanks for your help. However, I just need to know what's the base scenario used to define the installation minimum requirements. How does MSFT defines the specs?

Comment: HW & SW requirements for R2: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx. The version depends upon the features you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the min specs from Microsoft if that's what you're look for. It's not going to give you user counts and such: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx

Comment: The conventional wisdom across all the MSFT product lines is that the min specs rarely are adequate for real world operation. When you've got some more details on the types of apps you'll be running against SQL Server, size of data sets, number of concurrent users, etc. post back and we'll give you some more specific advice based on the usage.